# where is the stickman in the web?

Tags: html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<base href="http://www.w3schools.com/images/" target="_blank">
</head>

<body>
<img src="stickman.gif" width="24" height="39"> - Notice that we have only specified a relative address for the image. Since we have specified a base URL in the head section, the browser will look for the image at "http://www.w3schools.com/images/stickman.gif"
<br><br>
<a href="http://www.w3schools.com">W3Schools</a> - Notice that the link opens in a new window, even if it has no target="_blank" attribute. This is because the target attribute of the base element is set to "_blank".

</body>
</html>
```

when i open it with firefox ,can see a stickman in the web ,but i can not find it in 
**http://www.w3schools.com/images/stickman.gif/**,where is the gif ?

Answer (score 2):

remove last slash `/`

try this url:

> http://www.w3schools.com/images/stickman.gif

Answer (score 1):

The stickman is here: http://www.w3schools.com/images/stickman.gif

You have a rogue `/` on the end of your URL.